# Inline suggested edit reviews are truncated in medium-width windows

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing a suggested edit inline (not from the queue) on a site with the new “responsive” design, at a window width where normal content does fit, the diff window is truncated on both sides, as is the edit window after clicking “Improve Edit” or “Reject and Edit”.

[image: screenshot of an inline suggested edit review]

This is from [User-input values in first column with squares displayed in second column for multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007263/user-input-values-in-first-column-with-squares-displayed-in-second-column-for-mu/51007280#51007280) which happened to have a pending suggested edit at the time, after clicking the `Edit (1)` button. Note how the scroll bar is all the way to the left, but there's content that vanishes to the left of the window. That's in Chrome 67.0.3396.87 on Linux at zoom level 100%, with a window width of 800.

Note that I'm not complaining that the user interface isn't responsive yet (although now that this has been deployed to SO I'd expect it to be), but that the interface is completely unusable even with scrolling. In sites with the old UI, you can see all the content even if it requires scrolling.

Reviews done from the suggested edit review queue are ok (not responsive, but you can see the content by scrolling). Inline edits are ok. The problem is specific to inline suggested edit reviews.

Comment: I also see this problem on tex.se reviews

Comment: The same happens in [smaller devices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356860/364217).

Comment: Do any other modals have similar problems on narrower windows?

Comment: @V2Blast Not that I know of. The suggested edit window seems to now allow scrolling to the right, but it's still truncated on the left.

Comment: @V2Blast Can we have an update as to its current status on the work timeline? Other than your comment, this report has seen no activity from staff since its tagging as under review in November 2020. Is this a complicated fix?

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog: Not sure; I just happened to see the MSE post itself when it was recently edited. I'll follow up internally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! I just deployed a fix. Now the inline suggested edit window should be responsive to your screen size.

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, I long-click on the "Edit (1)" link and then open it in a new tab. That opens the regular review-queue interface, which has a workable responsive view. At least this way I can review the edit I just came across.

[image: "Edit (1)" link circled in red]