# Suggested-edits with weird format

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits, responsive-design

This was experienced in a Samsung Galaxy A30s with Android 10 using Google Chrome.

When a question or an answer has an edit, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64916471/5675325), from a user that doesn't have enough reputation for it to be approved right away we see something like

[image]

Clicking in edit(1) then we'll get

[image]

In this given view it's not possible to see what's on the left side but we'll be able to scroll to the right

[image]

This happens also when the edit shows up in only one column

[image]

Didn't manage to test in other communities but I assume this to be a general behavior.

Comment: @Luuklag but this is the responsive design (aka "full site"). I don't think this suggested edit screen is responsive yet.

Comment: @Luuklag, Kodos Johnson is right, i fixed the wrong tag usage. I started using the responsive design a while back after realizing the bugs reported in the mobile view weren't considered and the reason behind.

Comment: Some of the modals we use aren't "Stacksified" - which is what makes them responsive. I'm pretty sure this is one of them. If I understand correctly, the conversion to Stacks for a modal is somewhat challenging, particularly as we try to review the modal and see if it needs improvement rather than just copy-pasting it. I don't think we have this on our roadmap, unfortunately, but I'll check.

Comment: @Catija there are a few considerations when making modals more accessible, yes ([in more detail](https://robdodson.me/building-better-accessibility-primitives/)). Not sure what you mean with "Stacksified" though.

Comment: Stacks is our ... dunno... library of how the product should look? https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/

Comment: Oh great link, thank you for sharing @Catija! Stacks consists of reusable components (it has many advantages, like the one you just wrote). Can see in it that [Modals are already one of the existing components](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/modals/#examples). The existing Stack modals are "plain", so for this case it'd be required someone to decide how exactly it should look like smaller devices like my phone (that's normal procedure developing for the web - counting that different users might access in different devices (not sure where users are mostly coming from here))