# Please fix broken UI that prevents us from moderating properly

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, profile-page

The company has recently decided to "fix" things that haven't been broken and in the process broke more things. At the same time, bugs we have been asking to get fixed for ages are still not touched. I understand that there might be technical debt, but at least try to make our moderating activities easier, not harder.

In particular, I would like to beg for a fix of two things:

1. The suggested edit approval on mobile is still broken. I can't change the tag on a question because there's some edit pending and I can't review it because the modal is off-screen.
2. The reputation page in the activity tab of a user profile is very difficult to use. This prevents users and moderators from quickly checking voting fraud. Something that I liked to do and was very good at, now is an annoying guessing game because I can't efficiently use the reputation page to check whether the votes still require mods attention.

**Please stop making the UI responsive and fix burning issues!**

Comment: Might I suggest that one stop moderating instead?  It seems more likely that this would actually happen on any measurable time frame as opposed to the UI team paying this any mind.

Comment: The first question here is a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311648/1017231); maybe edit it out so that the question is more focused?

Comment: This is two unrelated questions, and should be split into two separate requests to permit voting on each. In addition, screenshots a specific example (even if staff are the only ones who could follow the URL), and constructive feedback help improve the likelihood of this getting priority over other better explained complaints.

Comment: You know that the fix for #1 is a more responsive UI, right?

Comment: If the UI is literally causing nausea then you should explain why/how because it reads as you being abusively insulting for no good reason.

Comment: @BSMP to me this looks like containing accurate descriptions of two problems. One about suggested edits I didn't fully grasp because I don't use this feature much recently but another one, about reputation page checks for indication of voting fraud I can fully confirm because I use it and the problem is indeed very painful. Could it be that you missed that because you don't use respective curation features, just like I didn't grasp about suggested edits for that reason?

Comment: @gnat I am saying that it is unclear whether OP’s use of the phrase “vomit-inducing” is literal or not.

Comment: @BSMP well, as one who actively uses the same page for the same purpose, this matches how I felt when I saw it changed. In prior comment I wrote "very painful", this is how I forced myself to sound polite at any cost

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Seizure_disorders

Comment: I agree with the sentiment here. However, I'd like to check in with you regarding the most recent changes to the profile pages, particularly the reputation pages. Do the adjustments which they recently made alleviate your feelings a bit regarding those pages? Ironically, I was working on a userscript to "fix" those pages and actively working on putting the finishing touches on a releasable version when they pushed the most recent changes (which, of course, negate the vast majority of what I was doing :; ).

Comment: @Makyen FWIW my observations also suggest that things somehow improved. I noticed some changes about a week ago but these were coincided with [this serious bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376544/165773) and I expected that fix for the bug will roll the improvements back. So far though it looks like improvements stay while the bug seems to be fixed

Comment: @Makyen A little bit yes. It is easier to look at it, but the time is still less visible than before. Investigating voting fraud is still much harder than last year. In "post" view the time is hidden away and is not sorted by time. In "time" view, we can't see individual votes. In my opinion, this is clearly buggy behaviour and it should be fixed. There are also other bugs that make this page unreliable.  To make this usable, we would need to clearly see the time of each vote without clicking and sorted by time. The "post" view can become what "time" view is now.

Comment: @Dharman At least for me, I'm more interested in view organized by time, but with every event listed, rather than something organized by post. The post view is only interesting because it can be made to show each event for the all posts, but for posts with more than one event that's an AJAX call per each post on each day where the post has more than one event. That's *really* inefficient. I've basically come to the reluctant conclusion that it's easier to either replace the time view or build an additional view (from a userscript POV).

Comment: From the POV of SE changing it, all that would need to happen is not group a post's events in the time view. Beyond that, it should be relatively easy to adjust the CSS and some JavaScript (at least in part because SE refuses to use an actual `<table>` when they are really displaying a table).

Comment: @Makyen Technically, this data is fully available via API and it gives more than was ever available in the profile. Getting this data from API is not as user-friendly though. A simple table with each event on a separate line with UTC time would be ideal. No grouping, no collapsable view. Just a simple table of all events with exact time for each one.

Comment: @Dharman Having previously looked at the data which is available from the SE API on several occasions, I'd want grouping on some things, probably along with day markers (e.g. I find it convenient to have the timestamps shown as only times (with difference/elapsed to prior event, where relevant), rather than an ISO date-time. Although that might be a remnant of the existing organization of that page. Rebuilding that view based  on data from the SE API has been on my list of things to do for a long time now.

Comment: Fixing bugs is way down the priority list of SE. They just throw bugs to huge review pool, and let them rot. Nice of you to try and change it but.... it just won't happen. That's how SE works. And if they'll stop working on Responsive view for some reason, they'll just fire the developers, or move them to different group, it's not like they'll magically start working on fixing bugs. This task is done by one single developer, in weekly rotation. The developer pick a bug (maybe random, never figured how it works) from the review pool and try to see what can be done with it. Usually nothing.