# Bugs in the new rep history page

Tags: bug, reputation, design, reputation-history

There are a number of bugs with the new reputation page. Since I haven't found any announcement post whereby we can post bugs, and since I've aggregated the bugs I've found here, I thought we could use use this post to track bugs with the new rep history page.

Other reported bugs:

- [Reputation tab shows +30, +40, +50, +60, +70, +80, +90, +100, +110, each as an individual event for one day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376538/1136431)

Comment: I added some other bugs related to this change. I would change the post title to remove the mention of bounty as this is not only related to bounty. Unless there's a bug tracker somewhere and these are all separate bugs.

Comment: Maybe also include that the bugs displayed here are from SO. Apparently, at least on my profile, the bug on MSE looks weirder: [Reputation tab shows +30, +40, +50, +60, +70, +80, +90, +100, +110, each as an individual event for one day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376538/773001)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in meta sites each bug should be reported as a new question. Such "threads" are just making huge mess and not monitored.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please change the way page numbers (in reputation page) looks like in mobile view. It looks bad IMO.

[image]

It looks better in desktop.

[image]

Comment: I think it has [already been fixed](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9130980#9130980) when the mobile version was removed.

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Long titles break the layout

[image]

Comment: Good catch! We should have a fix shipped for this in the next day.

Comment: @DanCormier its broken (either never fixed or broken again) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384926/280725

Comment: @dippas maybe the ship delivering the fix sank before reaching its destination.

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

New maths was invented. The numbers don't add up.

Should be +8 and in green:

[image]

Should be +10:

[image]

Should be +18 and in green:

[image]

Comment: I've noticed this too. It's tough to track down because I'm unable to reproduce locally but I've seen it in production. I'm unsure if it's a newly-introduced front-end issue or a long-standing backend issue, but I'm investigating.

Comment: @DanCormier it looks like it just makes the rep for that day red if a downvote occurred, and doesn't actually count the downvote. Could it be that simple?

Comment: @richardec pretty much! We were only using either the rep up, rep down, or 0 as the value instead of the computed rep change value. The color of the rep change is a separate issue where both green and red values would get applied in certain cases. Expect a fix soon!

Comment: Nice. Keep up the great work :)

Comment: @Dan will you please take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377193/1136431?

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When the first event of multiple on a post is a negative, the day-total reputation is red, even if it's positive:

[image]

(Hmm...that count isn't right either - it's not accounting for the downvote.)

Comment: Seems like a dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376553/818993

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems like the when multiple events happen on the same post on the same day, all events appear as the same one.

For example, on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70822887/17242583), the answerer got 1 upvote, 1 accept, and 1 bounty worth 100 rep. However, their rep history reports that they got *3 bounties worth 100 rep* (and only those):

[image]

Or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71152732/17242583), which had 1 upvote, 1 accept, and 1 answer worth 50 rep:

[image]

Comment: This issue should be resolved in the fix mentioned here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376552/163535

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Accepting your own answer does not show the reputation change (i.e. 0).

[image]

Comment: This issue appears to have been resolved in the broader Activity reputation item fix that went out mentioned here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376538/reputation-tab-shows-30-40-50-60-70-80-90-100-110-each-as-an-i/376556#376556

Comment: @DanCormier No, the issue is still not resolved. In the "time" view I still cannot see any number beside "accept"

Comment: you're correct. I intended to mark this as planned. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: This should be resolved now. Let me know if it's still an issue!

Comment: @DanCormier FYI apparently users have reported a [regression of this today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384925) -see the duplicate list, there's another post from March- and an SME confirmed in the answers he thinks it's happening.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "Time" and "Graph" views of rep history are completely messed up:

[image]

Comment: This should be resolved by the fix mentioned here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376552/163535

Answer (score 3):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

The time is visible only today when in "post" view.

[image]

Comment: In the previous iteration of the view, the timestamp only displayed on today's posts (and on items in the "time" view) because post reputation changes are grouped by date.

Answer (score 3):

Font sizes for day and individual posts are the same, but vertical whitespace is few pixels smaller for the individual post. This creates rather unpleasant visual experience and posts look cramped.

Either whitespace needs to be the same or the individual post needs smaller title font.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

The label for the upvote with 0 reputation gain (e.g. CW upvote) is misaligned.

[image][image]

...or they are all centered and just look really strange. Consider right-aligning them.

[image]

Comment: The label and number are right aligned overall to ensure it works for any reputation change that can occur.

Comment: @Dan Why does the label need to be right aligned?

Comment: The values of the rep change growing from left to right as numbers do seems more valuable than the condition of the rep change.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Reputation tab when sorting by time shows individual points exceeding total for day when new rep is yet unseen

It doesn't seem to be a calculation problem, **rather a display problem.**

> [image]

Above three new upvotes, but:

> [image]

That same answer is showing twice (two rows) ***with twice the total reputation*** (10+50 instead of 30).

Also I'm using the sort by time because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372934/392799), but that's unrelated.

Once the new is *seen,* it's correct:

> [image]

Since I've seen similar(?) status-completed reports, this is new as of March 6th.

Answer (score 2):

Since this post is specifically for the reputation tab, I'm reposting my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372934/392799) from the new responsive post since it wasn't status-tagged there:

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Fix the faint yellow coloring of the new reputation events when sorting by Post

> Why are events sometimes highlighted in yellow?
>
> This represents new events that you haven't seen yet regarding your reputation. They are only highlighted for that single view of the page. If you leave and return to your reputation history, they will no longer be highlighted. The total amount of the highlighted events should add up to the number in the bubble of the reputation tab itself (excluding any removed and reversal events). This bubble is meant to indicate the total amount your reputation has changed since you last checked the reputation tab. It will not appear until you've visited the tab at least once.
>
> — [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139615/392799)

The yellow highlighting only works when sorting by Time, and not also by Post as it used to:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax)

### Titles with MathJax are not wrapped correctly

[image]

Similar bugs have been reported for several other pages:

- [MathJax wraps awkwardly on the activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page/372605#372605): marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [MathJax layout problem on the main page, as well as in the 'All actions' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375474#375474): marked [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
- [Some titles containing MathJax are shown incorrectly in review queues](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34112/some-titles-containing-mathjax-are-shown-incorrectly-in-review-queues): marked [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) on Mathematics Meta

---

As a bonus, the above screenshot also shows that a long title starts on the next line and is incorrectly aligned, as reported here: [In the "Reputation" tab of my "Activity" page, a long post title starts on a completely new line with improper alignment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376859/986753).

Comment: See also: [MathJax text broken along several lines in post titles (in review queues)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369812/289905). I don’t think it’s specific to this page.

Answer (score 1):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

There's a useless tooltip that is not present on aggregate events.

[image]

Comment: If this tooltip was by-design, consider removing it and putting a legend at the bottom of the page. The tooltip doesn't convey any extra information and is just the longer representation of the label.

Comment: I'd agree with you if the text in the system tooltip matched the text in the UI completely (in this case, if it just said "upvote"), but for many users I can see this helping provide a little more context and detail, particularly with users new to this view.