# In the "Reputation" tab of my "Activity" page, a long post title starts on a completely new line with improper alignment

Tags: bug, reputation, design, reputation-history, activity

In the "Reputation" tab of my "Activity" page, a long post title starts on a completely new line, and the alignment is incorrect.

[image: Screenshot from my activity page on MathOverflow.]

---

Another report (perhaps related) regarding misalignment of a long title: [Followed posts start with an empty line if the post title is long. (In the activity summary.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372614/986753). The latter one is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), though.

Comment: Looks like this is already reported here: [Bugs in the new rep history page](/a/376545/289905).

Comment: Ah, there's a separate thread for bugs in the rep history page, forgot about that one... Thanks @SebastianSimon. But, the answer you linked is marked [status-completed], though?

Comment: No. @SebastianSimon that's no official thread and it's not monitored. Each bug **should be reported as a new question**. That's how meta works, sometimes people don't know it and make mistakes. The OP of the misguided thread is deleted by now though.