# Rep history color bugs again

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, design

Today I upvoted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71468625/17242583) that was unaccepted, and now in the author's reputation history I can see a `-5` event, but it's not red, it's **green**!

[image]

But I thought this [**was fixed**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376544/bugs-in-the-new-rep-history-page/376553#comment1255143_376553) last month?

Comment: No the color bug was [never fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376544/bugs-in-the-new-rep-history-page/376553#comment1255143_376553). ("Expect a fix soon" is codename for "we will never fix it, but don't want to hurt you by saying this")

Comment: @ShadowWizard I highly doubt though that this is the type of thing they'd put off fixing. Dan been willing to fix all the bugs we've pointed out, and it's far more likely that this is an oversight/edge case.

Comment: Green is correct. They could have been at a deep red  -15, now only at -5, worth a green color ...

Comment: @richardec Dan **has been** willing, past tense, when it was still fresh. Check it out yourself. Since Feb 25th, about three weeks ago, not a single comment or edit from him on the bugs reported since. I would be really glad to stand corrected and see him back fixing the bugs, but I have a feeling it just won't happen.

Comment: ;I pinged him...we'll see. I don't even know what kind of notifications he gets from SE...

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar Don't you think they did their best, but missed some details?

Comment: @Ann seems probable to me. All we can see is that "it's the same bug", but in reality there could be a hundred causes. Like you have the number 42, but you have no idea if it was made by `6*7` or `21+21` or what.

Comment: I implemented a fix to a similar but distinct bug recently (the one @richardec mentioned me in today). I'll look into this one and try to figure out what’s going on.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar FWIW, sorry for the delays. That Activity post specifically needs some love but is a bit of a mess and it's been hard for me to triage. I’ve addressed many issues in there still tagged review or planned in the course of development but I’ve neglected to update tags or comments because there’s so much to dig through.

Comment: After a few attempts at reproducing this locally and finding an active example in production (the linked user no longs reflects the issue), I've yet to come across this issue. If anyone knows of an active example (especially a rep change example from a prior date), please mention it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Dan Really! Well, another user upvoted that answer, so probably that's why. So unnaccepting an answer and the upvoting it doesn't work? Perhaps, since I assume you have live DB access, you can query for answers unaccepted today and upvote one?

Comment: I spoke too quick! I can reproduce it locally and now have a fix for the bug. The nested item for rep changes uses a different partial than the parent elements and that nested partial didn't receive the fix (yet). Expect a fix to ship within the next 24 hours.

Comment: @DanCormier well that's rare case where I'm glad to be wrong. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I thought this was fixed [last month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376544/bugs-in-the-new-rep-history-page/376553#comment1255143_376553)?

Yep! Well, the same bug in a different place was fixed. This is a classic case of [fixing a bug in one partial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376544/bugs-in-the-new-rep-history-page/376553#comment1255143_376553) when it exists in two. An additional fix has been shipped to production. Sorry for the confusion!

The function that sets the color of the reputation change used conditionals based on the reputation increase/decrease independent of one another instead of considering net reputation change. Basically, if *any* reputation increase occurred with a given entry, the net reputation change would have the green color applied.