# Long question titles break the reputation page

Tags: bug, reputation

Well, "break" might be a tad dramatic, but they definitely disrupt the formatting instead of being wrapped into two lines without overflowing into the reputation or date columns.
Seen on my [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik?tab=reputation) a few minutes before posting this, but a screenshot would last longer:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I've seen the same bug with Chrome (108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and Firefox (108.0.1 (64-bit)) on Windows 10 Enterprise (build 19044.2251).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It said it was been fixed back in [February](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376545/280725) but it is not fixed (or might been broken again).

The issue is the parent div `<div class="d-flex g4 p8 py2 md:p6 fw-wrap bb bc-black-075"><div>` has `fw-wrap` which makes the child element wrap when there is no enough space, removing it fixes the bug